# How to host a spring boot app with socket.io in azure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a spring boot app which has some http endpoint. I integrated netty-socketio for socket.io operations. I am deploying the app in azure using app services. I can get the http responses. But I can not connect to the socket.io.
how to connect with the socket?

My socket.io configuration looks like

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private int SOCKETPORT;

private SocketIOServer server;

@Bean
public SocketIOServer userStatusServer() {
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.setHostname("0.0.0.0");
   config.setPort(SOCKETPORT);
   // TODO:  set acknowledgement timeout here
   return socketIOServer(config);
}
```

Comment: Can you connect to the **socket.io** locally?

Comment: Are you using the **socket.io** client is it also a Spring boot application code?

Comment: Check this [link](https://devcodef1.com/news/1166074/spring-boot-netty-socket-io-on-azure) to deploy a Spring boot application using Netty Socket.IO to Azure App Services.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code in Spring Boot with Socket.IO and successfully deployed it to the Azure App Service.*

**Code :**

**MyController.java :**

```java
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private SocketIOServer socketIOServer;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/socket")
    public ResponseEntity<String> socketOperation(@RequestBody String data) throws IOException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(data);
        String message = jsonNode.get("message").asText();
        socketIOServer.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("socketEvent", message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(message);
    }
}
```

***NettySocketIOConfig.java :***

```java
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class NettySocketIOConfig {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int SOCKETPORT;

    @Bean
    public SocketIOServer socketIOServer() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("0.0.0.0");
        config.setPort(SOCKETPORT);
        return new SocketIOServer(config);
    }
}
```

***Application.java :***

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo", "com.example.demo.config"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

***pom.xml :***

```xml
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
          </dependency>
-    <dependency>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.66.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
          <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.16</version> <!-- or the latest version -->
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Output :**

The above code ran successfully, as shown below.

[image]
[image]

**Browser Output :**

[image]

I received the following output in Postman with a POST request.

[image]

I successfully deployed my project to the Azure App Services, as demonstrated below.

[image]

**Azure web apps output :**

[image]

I obtained the following output in Postman using a POST request.

[image]

**Reference :**  Check this [link](https://devcodef1.com/news/1166074/spring-boot-netty-socket-io-on-azure) .